# 2 forms on the same page using AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX/PHP for 2 forms on the same page (in Bootstrap modals). I might be going about this the wrong way, but I have 2 separate files that retrieve the POST info. I changed all of the variables and ids.

The first form works as expected - sends an email and tells the user "Message Submitted" at the bottom of the form. The second form sends the email, but doesn't give the user any feedback that it was received or give them an error if it is not.

It seems that the problem is function submitMSG - works on the first form, does nothing on the second.

I'm going to post my 2 .js files here - hopefully someone knows what I did wrong. Thanks!

Business form script

```
$("#businessForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
    formError();
    submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
} else {
    // everything looks good!
    event.preventDefault();
    submitFormBusiness();
}
});


function submitFormBusiness(){
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
var yourNameBusiness = $("#yourNameBusiness").val();
var yourEmailBusiness = $("#yourEmailBusiness").val();
var yourPhoneBusiness = $("#yourPhoneBusiness").val();
var yourStreetBusiness = $("#yourStreetBusiness").val();
var yourCityBusiness = $("#yourCityBusiness").val();
var yourStateBusiness = $("#yourStateBusiness").val();
var yourZipBusiness = $("#yourZipBusiness").val();
var accountBusiness = $("#accountBusiness").val();
var otherNameBusiness = $("#otherNameBusiness").val();
var otherBusinessBusiness = $("#otherBusinessBusiness").val();  
var otherEmailBusiness = $("#otherEmailBusiness").val();
var otherPhoneBusiness = $("#otherPhoneBusiness").val();
var otherStreetBusiness = $("#otherStreetBusiness").val();
var otherCityBusiness = $("#otherCityBusiness").val();
var otherStateBusiness = $("#otherStateBusiness").val();
var otherZipBusiness = $("#otherZipBusiness").val();
var humanBusiness = $("#humanBusiness").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "form-process-refer-a-business.php",
    data: "&yourNameBusiness=" + yourNameBusiness + "&yourEmailBusiness=" + yourEmailBusiness + "&yourPhoneBusiness=" + yourPhoneBusiness + "&yourStreetBusiness=" + yourStreetBusiness + "&yourCityBusiness=" + yourCityBusiness + "&yourStateBusiness=" + yourStateBusiness + "&yourZipBusiness=" + yourZipBusiness + "&accountBusiness=" + accountBusiness + "&otherNameBusiness=" + otherNameBusiness + "&otherBusinessBusiness=" + otherBusinessBusiness + "&otherEmailBusiness=" + otherEmailBusiness + "&otherPhoneBusiness=" + otherPhoneBusiness + "&otherStreetBusiness=" + otherStreetBusiness + "&otherCityBusiness=" + otherCityBusiness + "&otherStateBusiness=" + otherStateBusiness + "&otherZipBusiness=" + otherZipBusiness + "&humanBusiness=" + humanBusiness,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false,text);
        }
    }
});
}

function formSuccess(){
$("#businessForm")[0].reset();
submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!");
}

function formError(){
$("#businessForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
});
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
if(valid){
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
} else {
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
}
$("#businessSubmitMsg").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

Friends form script

```
$("#friendForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
    formError();
    submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
} else {
    // everything looks good!
    event.preventDefault();
    submitFormFriend();
}
});

function submitFormFriend(){
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
var yourNameFriend = $("#yourNameFriend").val();
var yourBusinessFriend = $("#yourBusinessFriend").val();
var yourEmailFriend = $("#yourEmailFriend").val();
var yourPhoneFriend = $("#yourPhoneFriend").val();
var yourStreetFriend = $("#yourStreetFriend").val();
var yourCityFriend = $("#yourCityFriend").val();
var yourStateFriend = $("#yourStateFriend").val();
var yourZipFriend = $("#yourZipFriend").val();
var accountFriend = $("#accountFriend").val();
var otherNameFriend = $("#otherNameFriend").val();
var otherBusinessFriend = $("#otherBusinessFriend").val();
var otherEmailFriend = $("#otherEmailFriend").val();
var otherPhoneFriend = $("#otherPhoneFriend").val();
var otherStreetFriend = $("#otherStreetFriend").val();
var otherCityFriend = $("#otherCityFriend").val();
var otherStateFriend = $("#otherStateFriend").val();
var otherZipFriend = $("#otherZipFriend").val();
var humanFriend = $("#humanFriend").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "form-process-refer-a-friend.php",
    data: "&yourNameFriend=" + yourNameFriend + "&yourBusinessFriend=" + yourBusinessFriend + "&yourEmailFriend=" + yourEmailFriend + "&yourPhoneFriend=" + yourPhoneFriend + "&yourStreetFriend=" + yourStreetFriend + "&yourCityFriend=" + yourCityFriend + "&yourStateFriend=" + yourStateFriend + "&yourZipFriend=" + yourZipFriend + "&accountFriend=" + accountFriend + "&otherNameFriend=" + otherNameFriend + "&otherBusinessFriend=" + otherBusinessFriend + "&otherEmailFriend=" + otherEmailFriend + "&otherPhoneFriend=" + otherPhoneFriend + "&otherStreetFriend=" + otherStreetFriend + "&otherCityFriend=" + otherCityFriend + "&otherStateFriend=" + otherStateFriend + "&otherZipFriend=" + otherZipFriend + "&humanFriend=" + humanFriend,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false,text);
        }
    }
});
}

function formSuccess(){
$("#friendForm")[0].reset();
submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!");
}

function formError(){
$("#friendForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass();
});
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
if(valid){
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
} else {
    var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
}
$("#friendSubmitMsg").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

Comment: So you have 2 functions with same name. How should browser understand which one should be called?

Comment: that's a good point. so just change the name of submitMSG to submitMSGFriend and submitMSGBusiness or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the function submitMSG is already defined (as u_mulder mentioned) and when the friend form is submitted, first submitMSG function is used. Thus the message should be appearing at the bottom of the #bussinessForm form. So like you mentioned, changing the name of the submitMSG function so that each form has a different function name should work.

Another way to solve this is to pass the form element along through the functions so that each function performs its action on the element that was passed to it for example:

```
$('.msg-form').validator().on('submit', function (event) {
    var self = $(this);

    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError(self, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitMessageForm(self);
    }
});

function submitMessageForm (form) {
    var data = new FormData();

    form.find('.input-field').each(function () {
        data.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
        //or you could define a var 'params' outside the 
        //loop and add the params like
        //var params += $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val() + '&';
        //Just remember to remove the last & afterwards
    });

    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess(form, "Message Submitted!");
            } else {
                formError(form, text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(form, message){
    form[0].reset();
    submitMSG(form, true, message);
}

function formError(form, message){
    form.removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });

    submitMSG(form, false, message);
}

function submitMSG(form, valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    form.removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks. Besides changing the name of submitMSG, I also had to change the name of a couple other functions -formSuccess and formError. I didn't realize all of these had to be unique.

I want to try your method because I have a bunch of extra code. But for now, this gets the job done.